# Can I re-use the package name of a draft app in a new application after deleting it from Google Play console?

Tags: google-play

I've created an application in Google Play Console, and made a simple mistake and I can't continue using it.

It is a draft application, and I uploaded an APK to Beta, which is not enrolled.
Can I delete this draft application and re-use the package name in a new application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted play console help, and they said I could delete my app and recreate a new one. But they had to check the package name.

If you have the same problem try contacting them by going to the following link:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contactflow?hl=en